# How do I write and read to a JSON file inside the applicationSupportDirectory? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to save a struct as a JSON file inside app's applicationSupportDirectory and then read it later to a different variable, in a different file. However, when I try to decode and read from that file afterwards, I get a

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

These are my **structs**:

```
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var organization: String
    var location: String
    var description: String
    
    private var imageName: String
    
    var image: Image{
        Image(imageName)
    }
    
    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, organization: String, location: String, description: String, imageName: String, coordinates: Coordinates) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.organization = organization
        self.location = location
        self.description = description
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.coordinates = coordinates
    }
    
}

struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}
```

This is how I save the event in appDirectory:

```
func saveDataToSupportDirectory( event: Event) {
   
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("eventData.json")

        try JSONEncoder().encode(event).write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
}
```

This is how I read it in a different file after successfully running `saveDataToSupportDirectory`. Well, at least I believe that it's successful because it doesn't show errors. To be honest, I don't know how to see what files are in that directory.

```
var events: [Event] = load("eventData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    //Load the file into data
    do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("eventData.json")
        data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load data")
    }
    
    do{
        return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
        fatalError("Couldn't decode data")
    }

}
```

Comment: You’ve encoded a singular object but you’re trying to decode an array

Comment: Oh, thank you @jnpdx! So do you have an idea how could I encode it as an array or encode several Event structs at the same time? Would I have to encode an array containing several instances of Events? I'm trying to have an eventData.json to contain multiple events and then load them inside my app as an array so I can use them in a list.

Comment: You can modify your save function to take an array instead of a single event.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been resolved (in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the type you are trying to encode and decode. In my example, I was trying to encode a singular object event and decode an array of events. Credits to @jnpdx!